# Docker container IP blocked by corporate firewall

Tags: docker, routes

I have a server that has to communicate to a mail server (IMAP, via port 143) inside a corporate network.
In order to reach the IMAP server I asked to IT team to open the route through the corporate firewall (using my IP address).
All worked fine.

I want now to reach the mail server from a Docker container, but it doesn't work because the different IP address of the source (the container indeed).

Is there a way to communicate with the mail server (or in general with another service) from a Docker container without edit the rules of the corporate firewall?

Comment: What's your host machine? Linux, Windows, Mac? If you are on Linux, you could always use the [host network](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/): [`docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx`](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/)

Comment: I'm on a Linux machine, your solution works fine! Thank you!

Comment: Nope. This work fine for a single container. How do i configure the network and the services in order to resolve this problem?

Comment: Using docker-compose then?

Comment: Yes. But if I set `network_mode: "host"` to all services, I cannot use `depends_on` or `links` (see: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode)